# Run PHP script "forever" in a VPS server

Tags: php, linux, service, console, infinite-loop

I am sure this must be very easy, but I have no experience with unix.
I have a PHP script that is a TCP client and registers received data into a mySQL database.
How can I have that PHP script running forever? I have root access via a console.
From time to time I may need to stop it, change it and restart it again.
Please advice.
Kind regards

Comment: Why not use a CRON that just populates the data not previously processed? Execute every minute, or 5 minutes, etc.. or if you realllly wanted to run forever `while(true) { do this forever }` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: presumably the script keeps its self alive (infinite loop) so you just need to start it from the console `>php somescript.php`

Comment: Yes, the script keeps itself alive because it must receive a TCP stream and it can not "loose" data. But how to call the script and and leave in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If script don't exit itself (have a loop inside), you can start it by `php script.php &`